# Facebook Graph/FQL Search By Date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am looking for a way to query the Facebook's public post by a date offset. I'm looking for all public post that are older than 15 minutes.

Is this possible in the graph?

In FQL, if this possbile, what timezone should I use if I try to query against created_time or updated_time?

Answer (score 0):

With "all public post" you mean all posts that are public on facebook or do you mean all posts on your timeline?

I don't think that facebook will allow you to copy the entire public post database.

Comment: All meaning the post that fit the query. But the all part is not important, it is the date of the post that is the focus.

Comment: Facebook *does* allow it.

Comment: in the graph api you can try something like `me/feed?until=<unixts>`